# How do I use an bean exported from a directory below?

Tags: java, xml, spring

Think for example that I have a Directory A that holds A.spring and Directory B. Inside Directory B is B.spring that defines a bean say "WANTED_BEAN". Also in Directory B is a main.spring that exports "WANTED_BEAN". How do I reuse this exported bean in A.spring?

The hierarchy below explains it much better.

- Directory A

  - A.spring (want to use bean here)
  - Directory B

    - main.spring (bean exported here)
    - B.spring (bean defined here)

Comment: how is this directory structure related to the classpath?

Comment: By creating an instance of it :S what is the question ??

Comment: The question is how do I reuse/reference/import this bean so that I can use it in A.spring?

Answer (score 0):

While you're talking about directories I expect what you're saying is that you have a few different spring context definition XML files located in those directories.

Spring has a concept of parent/child `ApplicationContext`s but merely locating the context configuration in a directory structure does not imply that Spring will look at it that way.

You don't say how you're constructing your `ApplicationContext` so it's  bit difficult to make comment, but:

[Composing XML-based configuration metadata](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import) explains how to `import` one XML configuration file from another.

If, on the other hand, you're creating an `ApplicationContext` within your application with paths supplied when you configure it, you should look at the reference for [Instantiating a container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation) and probably also [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) documentation.

You're should be either doing

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"A/A.spring", "B/B.spring", "B/main.spring"});
```

or

```
<beans>
    <import resource="A/A.spring"/>
    <import resource="B/B.spring"/>
    <import resource="B/main.spring"/>
</beans>
```